# Amazon instant video 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: amazon

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and I am having trouble using Amazon Instant Video. When I click on a video to play there is no option to play it, it just says that I can play it on a compatible device (kindle, phone,...) is there some package or something that I need to install?

Thanks for any help

I have successfully (I think) implemented the solution below but I still have the same problem.

After following the below I get:

```
nathan@nathan-S400CA:~$ sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/preprobe   
[sudo] password for nathan:     
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/hal/fdi/preprobe’: File exists    
nathan@nathan-S400CA:~$ sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/information    
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/hal/fdi/information’: File exists    
nathan@nathan-S400CA:~$ /usr/sbin/hald --daemon=yes --verbose=yes    
18:56:04.123 [I] hald.c:672: hal 0.5.14    
18:56:04.123 [I] hald.c:673: using child timeout 250s    
18:56:04.123 [I] hald.c:685: Will daemonize    
18:56:04.123 [I] hald.c:686: Becoming a daemon    
nathan@nathan-S400CA:~$ rm -rf ~/.adobe
```

Comment: Did you reboot ?

Comment: @markkirby Yeah, and it has done something as I can now watch other videos (on sites such as 4od) but when on Amazon instant there isn't even an option to press play it seems to think that I am looking at it from a device that isn't compatible for some reason

Comment: I updated the answer to include the next step for you.

Comment: @markkirby Thanks. I have entered those commands and posted what I got above into my answer

Comment: Reboot make sure the web browser is closed then open a terminal and type hald

Comment: Press enter,now try your video again

Comment: @markkirby Still no change

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need this flash plug in

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mjblenner/ppa-hal
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install hal
```

Here is a post with more information [LINK](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2206177) Post number 3

If after a reboot it wont work then copy paste this to a terminal, ONE LINE AT A TIME

```
sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/preprobe
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/information

/usr/sbin/hald --daemon=yes --verbose=yes

rm -rf ~/.adobe
```

Do not be worried by these commands enter them one at a time and tell me of any errors ,reboot when you are finished.

OK If this is not working for you we will try another way, open terminal run one at a time

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

If a Microsoft core fonts licence screen comes up, first perss the **tab** key and then enter.

next run this command (this undoes what we first tried)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge hal
```

And finally

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable flash
```

You could reboot here don't think you need to up to you.

Open your web browser and go to your video, the browser shoud automaticly try to download a plug in, give it permission if you have to.

When it is installed close your browser then open it again and it should work

To get silverlight close the browser

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

Open the browser go to the video and the plug in will install then restart the browser.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can do this without the use of command lines and so on just using th gui?

Comment: Why I wrote all the code for you copy and paste into the terminal, copy one line press enter,enter your password, say yes or press enter if it asks, repet for the last two lines.

Comment: I made it even simpeler for you only one command copy the whole thing and paste in a terminal,enter your password, press enter if it ask you for confirmation. Job done

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me I've pasted the message I got into my question

Comment: He was missing some commands: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install hal` will finish your installation properly.

Comment: Please just enter them one at a time then

Comment: @Jorge thanks I did not realize the first command is add-apt and the rest apt-get, so could not do one code, have fixed

Comment: I have done this successfully (I think) but I still get the same problem?

Comment: did you reboot ?

Comment: You using firefox or chrome ?

Comment: Thanks, I have done this and I am just reeboting now, I am using firefox (sorry for the delay)

Comment: delay is ok  will finish now

Comment: @markkirby my browser downloaded something called wine-flash, I closed my browser and re-opened but I still can't watch the video. I also re-booted just in case

Comment: Ok In firefox go to plug ins and find User Agent Overrider. Install this use its icon to change to a firefox windows option and try again

Comment: @markkirby And we are there! Thank you so much for the help that was great!

Comment: @markkirby Hey I don't know if you are still around but I have had another problem. It now says that I require silverlight to play videos on amazon instant. Is there a way to get this on ubuntu?

Comment: Yes what we did before was install the windows flash plug in so we can do silverlight the same. Will edit for you.

Comment: This solution seems to only work for firefox. It does not fix Chrome.  However Chrome already worked with netflix it just doesn't work with amazon.  Ideally we could fix Chrome too but I'm good with just firefox.