# Old solutions for making Amazon prime videos play on Firefox and Chrome not working on 15.04

Tags: 15.04, firefox, video, amazon

Solutions at this link [Amazon instant video 14.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515879/amazon-instant-video-14-04-1-lts) are not working for my current install. It did work on 14.04. I been trying to figure this out for a few days. Tried both the hal and moonlight suggestions. Help!

Answer (score 0):

I had chromium on my machine but chrome https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/thankyou.html?platform=linux itself did work.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a port of my solution on Debian Jessie, which your version of Ubuntu is based on (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244738/how-to-make-the-drm-protected-video-stream-of-amazon-video-run-on-debian-jessie/).

Install pipelight as described on the website (http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html):

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi`
- `sudo pipelight-plugin --update`

Enable Silverlight:

- `sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight`

Start Firefox and it should install Silverlight. Look into the extensions of Firefox to confirm that. If it's not listed there, you might got a problem with AppArmor. As noted on the project site in the link above you should set AppArmor into complain mode (to prevent disabling third-party plugins):

- `sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils`
- `sudo aa-complain usr.bin.firefox`

To confirm that Silverlight 5.1 is detected correctly with pipelight, you can use a test site (e.g. http://fds-team.de/pipelight/).

Now change your user agent with an extension (User-Agent Switcher 0.1.3, https//addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-firefox/) to simulate a Firefox running on Windows.

Run a test on a website to see whether Silverlight is loaded and streaming video properly (http//support.akamai.com/silverlight/). It should play the video over there.

Please note, that you should deactivate all extensions (especially like NoScript) for testing purposes. That's because they might interfer with Silverlight.

Go test Amazon Video.

On Debian the Amazon Video still didn't load. I figured out my filesystem was missing extended attributes. I assume you might run into this problem, too. You can fix it by doing these steps:

- Install the package `attr` with `sudo apt-get install attr`.
- Activate the attributes in `/etc/fstab` by adding the mount option `user_xattr`.
- Reload `fstab` with `sudo mount -a`.

It should work now. Have fun.